# SQL changes disappear after VS restart

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am learning the basics of C# and SQL interaction, and I have this form:

[image]

It shows me the values from a pre-filled DB made with VS 2013 DB builder and **everything works fine on the upper buttons**.

Here's my table:

[image]

**The problem:**

- When I click Add New, the textboxes are cleared;
- Next, fill the textboxes and when I click Save, the record is apparently added to the DB (or at least to the DataSet?), as it gives me a successfull message and is shown when I navigate through DB with the upper buttons;
- If I close and reopen **my application (without closing VS)**, the record that I inserted **is still there**.
- But if I **close and reopen VS** and run my application again, the record that I entered **is gone**.
- Also, without closing VS, if I go to the Server Explorer (VS left pane), rigth-click my table => Show Table Data, the new record is never there.

Here's the Form1.cs code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SQLtest
{
/// <summary>
/// A class that constains our form
/// </summary>
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    // variables
    DBconnection objConnect;
    string conString;
    DataSet ds;
    DataRow dr;
    int maxRows;
    int inc = 0;

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor of the class
    /// </summary>
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Form initialization method
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            objConnect = new DBconnection();
            conString = Properties.Settings.Default.TestConnectionString;

            objConnect.connection_string = conString;
            objConnect.Sql = Properties.Settings.Default.SQL;

            ds = objConnect.GetConnection;

            maxRows = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
            // MessageBox.Show("Max Rows: " + maxRows);

            NavigateRecords();
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
        }
    }

    // DB Navigation Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets pointer (inc) to last row
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // prevent indexOutOfBounds error
        if (inc != maxRows - 1)
        {
            inc++;
            NavigateRecords();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Reached last employee. Showing the first record.");
            inc = 0;
            NavigateRecords();
        }

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets pointer (inc) to previous row (if possible)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void btnPrevious_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // prevent indexOutOfBounds error
        if (inc != 0)
        {
            inc--;
            NavigateRecords();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Reached first employee. Showing the last record.");
            inc = maxRows - 1;
            NavigateRecords();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets pointer (inc) to first row
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void btnFirst_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (inc != 0)
        {
            inc = 0;
            NavigateRecords();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Already on first employee.");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets pointer (inc) to last row
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void btnLast_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (inc != maxRows - 1)
        {
            inc = maxRows - 1;
            NavigateRecords();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Already on last employee.");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Main Navigation Method
    /// </summary>
    private void NavigateRecords()
    {
        dr = ds.Tables[0].Rows[inc];

        txtFirstName.Text = dr.ItemArray.GetValue(1).ToString();
        txtLastName.Text = dr.ItemArray.GetValue(2).ToString();
        txtJobTitle.Text = dr.ItemArray.GetValue(3).ToString();
        txtDepartment.Text = dr.ItemArray.GetValue(4).ToString();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Exit button handler
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Add new record Button. Simply clears text fields, ready for a new record to be added.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void btnAddNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtFirstName.Clear();
        txtLastName.Clear();
        txtJobTitle.Clear();
        txtDepartment.Clear();

        btnAddNew.Enabled = false;
        btnSave.Enabled = true;
        btnCancel.Enabled = true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Save a new record button
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataRow newRow = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();

        // newRow[0] is the id, thus its filled automatically
        newRow[1] = txtFirstName.Text;
        newRow[2] = txtLastName.Text;
        newRow[3] = txtJobTitle.Text;
        newRow[4] = txtDepartment.Text;

        ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(newRow);

        try
        {
            objConnect.UpdateDB(ds);
            maxRows++;
            inc = maxRows - 1;

            MessageBox.Show("DB updated successfully");
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
        }

        btnAddNew.Enabled = true;
        btnSave.Enabled = false;
        btnCancel.Enabled = false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Cancel new record button. Simply call NavigateRecords() method, and restores buttons.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NavigateRecords();

        btnAddNew.Enabled = true;
        btnSave.Enabled = false;
        btnCancel.Enabled = false;
    }

}
}
```

And here's the DBconnection.cs code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SQLtest
{
/// <summary>
/// A class that makes the connection to the SQL Database
/// </summary>
class DBconnection
{
    // variables
    private string sql_string;
    private string strCon;
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter da_1;

    // set methods
    public string Sql
    {
        set { sql_string = value; }
    }

    public string connection_string
    {
        set { strCon = value; }
    }

    // DataSet
    public System.Data.DataSet GetConnection
    {
        get { return MyDataSet(); }
    }

    // MyDataSet method
    private System.Data.DataSet MyDataSet()
    {
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(strCon);
        con.Open();

        da_1 = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sql_string, con);

        System.Data.DataSet dat_set = new System.Data.DataSet();
        da_1.Fill(dat_set,"Table_Data_1");

        con.Close();

        return dat_set;
    }

    // Update DB method
    public void UpdateDB(System.Data.DataSet ds)
    {
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder cb = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder(da_1);
        cb.DataAdapter.Update(ds.Tables[0]);
    }
}
}
```

**EDIT:**

To test that VS copies DB.mdf to "/bin/Debug" folder, I added a new record, then detached DB from Server Explorer and copied DB.mdf from "/bin/Debug" folder and replaced the DB.mdf on main project folder. It confirms that this maybe the problem, as now I can see the newly added record through VS DB Designer.

Now I just need to figure out how to update the changes made to the DB.mdf on "/bin/Debug" folder to the main project DB.mdf on VS shutdown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that running your program copies the database from the root project folder to the Release or Debug folder so everytime you run your program, you will be working with a fresh copy of the database. It means any modification to the database you make will be overwritten and discarded the next time you run your application. This is good when you are just developing the application. If you don't want this behavior, select the database file (.mdf) in the Solution Explorer and in the find the Copy To Output Directory option in the Properties Window. Change its value to Copy if newer. The database file in the project's root directory will now only be coppied if it a newer version of the one that already exists in the output directory.

Apparently when you first create your solution/project database it is created in the parent directory of your project.
Afterward when you build/debug your solution it adds the database in the Bin/Debug directory. Any changes you make to your data while debugging are made in the Debug database.
However, when you run your application each time in VS it pulls the data from the parent directory which never received the changes that you made while debugging because the changes were actually made in the Debug database.

**Solution:**

- In database explorer
- Right click on the database
- Select modify connection
- Advanced options
- Search for the property AttachDbFileName
- Change it to the DB from debug folder c:...\bin\debug\DB.mdf
- Once you point your database to the Debug directory, in VS Server Explorer, you can then delete the database in the solution explorer and all updates will transpire in the Debug database.

Comment: Select the databases in Solution Explorer and change the "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy if newer". Later, when you finally get the final version, copy paste the databases in debug folder to your source folders

Comment: I have already done that after a google search, it made my app see the changes even after restarts, but when restarting VS, DB clears those changes. Already tried to set it to "Do Not Copy", but it gives me an error and doesn't connects to DB.

Comment: Try Copy if newer  option and check. This setting persists any changes made to the data during run time, meaning that every time you run your application and save changes to the data, those changes are visible the next time you run your application.